# How to set minDate value in CoreUI bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, bootstrap-4, core-ui

I read the documentation here: https://coreui.io/docs/forms/date-range-picker/#disabled-dates

However I cant seem to make it work by putting the attribute instead of javascript: https://coreui.io/docs/forms/date-range-picker/#options

```
<div data-coreui-toggle="date-picker"
    data-coreui-indicator="false"
    data-coreui-cleaner="true"
    data-coreui-size="sm"
    data-coreui-locale="en-US"
    data-coreui-date="{{ old('date-picker-check_in') }}"
    data-coreui-min-date="10/01/2022"
    class="bottom"
    id="check_in">
</div>
```

has anyone have experienced this as well?

I also tried emailing support but they have not replied yet.

Answer (score 0):

change code like this :

```
<div data-coreui-toggle="date-picker"
    data-coreui-indicator="false"
    data-coreui-cleaner="true"
    data-coreui-size="sm"
    data-coreui-locale="en-US"
    data-coreui-date="{{ old('date-picker-check_in') }}"
    data-coreui-minDate="10/01/2022"
    class="bottom"
    id="check_in">
</div>
```

I hope it will work!